# Format a number xxxx to be xx/xx in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I format a number(or string) xxxx to be xx/xx in AngularJS?
I have a string of 4 digits and I want to know how can I format like this: XX/XX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is more of a javascript question than angularjs one unless you are talking about using a filter to do it. You could use that code to do it if your number will always have 4 digits:

```
app.filter('addDelimiter', function () {
  return function (number) {
    var firstPart = number.slice(0,2);
    var lastPart = number.slice(2,4);
    var delimeter = "/";
    var result = firstPart +delimeter+lastPart;
    return result
  };
});
```

With that filter you would be able to use it like that

```
{{ number | addDelimiter}}
```

and it would return xx/xx

Comment: And there isn't form to do it in the angular template? I know there are many forms to format Date(e.g) (like: {{ Date | format:yyyy:mm:dd }})

Comment: You can build your own filter to work like that. It would look like {{ yourfilter | number }}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{"XXYY".slice(0, 2) + "/" + "XXYY".slice(2)}}
```

You can replace `"XXYY"` with your scope variable.